Cab unable to take card payment
A few weeks ago, I took a cab from home to a London airport, and the journey cost about £60. They advertised that they were able to accept cards.
I offered to pay by card when I arrived, but the machine wasn’t working. The driver said no problem, the company would call later, and I could pay then.
Fast forward a week, and I heard nothing, so I called and asked to pay. It was in the evening, and they said they couldn’t deal with it now, so they’ll call me back.
It’s been three weeks since the trip, and they haven’t called.
How long until I write this off? I have tried to pay twice now, and they aren’t making it easy.

Have you tried phoning during business hours? That seems like a reasonable thing to do.

Have you tried contacting them by other means eg email or website enquiry form?

Phone them at a slack time, during the day when more admin staff will be around. Not in the rush hours. The people who answer the phone take bookings, so ask to speak to someone who can help.

If they have your details, and you are not trying to evade the payment, I'd say that the ball is in their court. And as per the driver, they will call you.

This is probably more suited for law.SE or money.SE.

Some local authorities require the taxi to take card payments as a condition of licence, and if it's "not working" then the vehicle is unfit to work, as when the brake is "not working". Drivers are not usually employees but owners or renters, and the payment goes directly to the driver, who pays the agency a booking fee. Some are in the black economy, wanting cash with no audit trail – but they don't want to risk the licence. It's possible that the driver hasn't told the company that payment was not collected. You aren't evading the fare. You offered payment, and the driver declined it.

@WeatherVane: I wouldn't say the driver declined payment - rather, they offered to accept payment at an (unspecified) later date.  So there is a debt that needs to be paid within a reasonable time.  It's just a matter of working out how to do that.

There are two scenarios where a passenger commits a criminal offence: 1. Making off without payment (Section 3 of the Theft Act 1978). The passenger runs off without paying. 2. Obtaining services dishonestly (Section 11 Fraud Act 2006). The person knowingly takes a journey without having the funds to pay but does not notify the driver until arrival at the intended destination. Similarly, the passenger outright refuses to pay at the intended destination. Neither apply to the OP, so the debt becomes a civil matter. A taxi driver who lets you off without paying is an odd situation IMHO

Thanks for all your comments. Funnily enough today I received quite an angry voicemail from the cab driver saying it was unfair I hadn’t paid yet.
Seems odd to me as this is the first I’d heard from him since the trip and I had offered to pay twice. Not worth the hassle (and I was happy with the trip itself) so I called the company again and they were able to take payment this time.

@WeatherVane and that includes Transport For London which regulates all London taxis. So the cab was not fit for operation,  possibly without the knowledge of the driver at that point (assuming good intentions by the driver, it's likely he had someone pay with a card not long before this ride).

@CGRalph the cabby likely gets paid only every few weeks for all the rides in the previous period. Easier on the company and likely cheaper as it means lower transaction fees with banks. So he probably didn't know the ride hadn't been paid for yet, nor the reason.

@jwenting makes sense
